# How to find values of variables that will linearize a non-linear equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-system

I want to find values for $a$, $b$, and $c$ that will make $y(x)$ a 'more linear' equation from $x=0$ to $x=100$ where $y(0)=0$. How do I find values for $a$, $b$, and $c$ that satisfy the two conditions below?

Values should satisfy the following two conditions:

1) $y(0)=0$

2) $y(50)=(1/2)y(100)$

Equation I wish to 'linearize':

$y(x)=5(ab-d(x)c)/(b(a+c))$

$d(x)=10000exp(3900(1/(x+273.15)+1/298))$

**My attempt:**

$y(0)=0$      is satisfied when    $d(0)/a=b/c$

$d(0)=32891$ therefore $a=32891c/b$

Substituting $a=32891c/b$ into the general equation $y(50)=(1/2)y(100)$ yields:

$c/b=0.08552$

Substituting $c/b=0.08552$ into the general equation $d(0)/a=b/c$ yields:

$a=384600$

I don't really know where to go from here to find $b$ and $c$ (or even if I correctly solved for a). The $d(x)$ in the equation makes this difficult for me to set up a system of equations.

Comment: Since $d(x)$ isn't linear, there is no way to choose values of $a,b,c$ to make $y$ linear in $x$ (exccept to choose $c=0$, which will make $y$ constant, which is probably not what you want).

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry, I just want to get it as close to linear as possible. I've edited the question to clarify. The resulting line will curve slightly above the the desired line, cross at y(50) then curve slightly below the desired line, and cross again at y(100).

Comment: "as linear as possible" is not a well-defined concept. The way you define it will affect the answer you want. So you must be more precise.

Comment: @GerryMyerson How do I find $a$, $b$, and $c$ that satisfy these two conditions: 1) $y(0)=0$ and 2) $y(50)=(1/2)y(100)$ If these two conditions are satisfied then the equation is 'linear enough'.

Comment: You have already done that. You have found $a=384600$ (I haven't checked your calculations, but I'll assume they're correct), and you have found $b/c=.08552$, and now you can choose $b$ to be whatever you like, and calculate the value of $c$ (or let $c$ be whatever you like, and calculate the corresponding value of $b$). Two conditions will generally not be enough to pin down three unknowns, they will leave you with one degree of freedom to play with.

Comment: So, are we OK now?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Comment: Good! Let me encourage you to write up what you know now, and post it as an answer.